# Select a TextRange in PowerPoint VB

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

First of all I'm selecting a slide by it's ID. Once that is done I'm trying to select a TextRange so it appears like the image below, however, I keep getting an index out of bounds exception and I've no idea why.

I've also tried selecting the TextRange like this `foundText.Select()`

[image]

My code is as follows

```
     _PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(slideID).Select()

            For Each slide As PowerPoint.Slide In _PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides
                If slideID = slide.SlideID Then
                    For Each shape As PowerPoint.Shape In slide.Shapes
                        If shape.Name = slideShape Then
                            Dim foundText = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(linkText)
                            If Not foundText Is Nothing Then
                            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(foundText.Start, foundText.Start + foundText.Length).Select()
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: Define foundText as Boolean.  What setting do you have for Option Infer?

Comment: @SezMeThe error  isn't in the if statement the error occurs on this line `shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(foundText.Start, foundText.Start + foundText.Length).Select()`

Comment: I was not talking about your error but rather noting good VB coding practice.